# Toad Sql Loader CTRL file

Tags: oracle, toad

I am using SQL loader in Toad first  time, how do i build CTRL file in SQl Loader wizard of toad. I have one table with one filed (ID) and i have a CSV file with one field (ID) i want to load that in table using SQL loader. Please Advise.

Database:- Oracle
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I figured out we can. Its very simple, we can do Database--> Import SQL loader wizard--->Select build CTRL file (or use existing if u have one) option-->Then Add input fiel name in the next window, select yr txt or CSV file--->leave rest of the default options-->in next window leave default option--> Next add schema and table name you want to import data to, load meathod insert or update (depends wht yo are trying to do)-->terminated by EOF tab or comma->Next leave the default option-->Save contol file--> Just build ctrl file or execute to load.